# How to create a custom TabView with NavigationView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

[EDIT] - This question has been edited and simplified.

I need to create a CustomLooking TabView instead of the default one.

Here is my full code with the problem. Just run the code below.

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum TabName {
    case explore, network
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var displayedTab: TabName = .explore
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            switch displayedTab {
            case .explore: AViewWhichNavigates(title: "Explore").background(Color.yellow)
            case .network: AViewWhichNavigates(title: "Network").background(Color.green)
            }
            Spacer()
            CustomTabView(displayedTab: $displayedTab)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTabView: View {
    @Binding var displayedTab: TabName
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Explore").border(Color.black, width: 1).onTapGesture { self.displayedTab = .explore }
            Spacer()
            Text("Network").border(Color.black, width: 1).onTapGesture { self.displayedTab = .network }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct AViewWhichNavigates: View {
    let title: String
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView(content: {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("We are one level deep in navigation")) {
                Text("You are at root. Tap to navigate").navigationTitle(title)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

On tab#1 click the navigation. Switch to tab#2, then Switch back to tab#1. You will see that tab#1 has popped to root.

How do I prevent the customTabView from popping to root every time i switch tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a ZStack with opacity.

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum TabName {
    case explore, network
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var displayedTab: TabName = .explore
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                AViewWhichNavigates(title: "Explore")
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .opacity(displayedTab == .explore ? 1 : 0)
                AViewWhichNavigates(title: "Network")
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .opacity(displayedTab == .network ? 1 : 0)
            }
            CustomTabView(displayedTab: $displayedTab)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTabView: View {
    @Binding var displayedTab: TabName
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Explore").border(Color.black, width: 1).onTapGesture { self.displayedTab = .explore }
            Spacer()
            Text("Network").border(Color.black, width: 1).onTapGesture { self.displayedTab = .network }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct AViewWhichNavigates: View {
    let title: String
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView(content: {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("We are one level deep in navigation")) {
                Text("You are at root. Tap to navigate").navigationTitle(title)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Navigation isActive state is not recorded as well as the displayed tab state.

By recording the state of the navigation of each tab as well as which tab is active  the correct navigation state can be show for each tab.

The model can be improved to remove the tuple and make it more flexible but the key thing is the use of getter and setter to use an encapsulated model of what the navigation state is for each tab in order to allow the NavigationLink to update it via a binding.

I have simplified the top level VStack and removed the top level switch as its not needed here, but it can be added back for using different types of views at the top level in a real implementation

---

```
enum TabName : String {
    case Explore, Network
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var model =  TabModel()
    
    init(){
         UINavigationBar.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            AViewWhichNavigates(model: $model).background(Color.green)
            Spacer()
            CustomTabView(model:$model)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTabView: View {
    @Binding var model: TabModel
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Explore").border(Color.black, width: 1).onTapGesture { model.selectedTab = .Explore }
            Spacer()
            Text("Network").border(Color.black, width: 1).onTapGesture { model.selectedTab = .Network }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct AViewWhichNavigates: View {
    @Binding var model:TabModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView(content: {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("We are one level deep in navigation in \(model.selectedTab.rawValue)"), isActive: $model.isActive) {
                Text("You are at root of \(model.selectedTab.rawValue). Tap to navigate").navigationTitle(model.selectedTab.rawValue)
            }.onDisappear {
                UINavigationBar.setAnimationsEnabled(model.isActive)
            }
        })
    }
}

struct TabModel {
    var selectedTab:TabName = .Explore
    var isActive : Bool {
        get {
            switch selectedTab {
                case .Explore : return tabMap.0
                case .Network : return tabMap.1
            }
        }
        set {
            switch selectedTab {
                case .Explore : nOn(isActive, newValue); tabMap.0 = newValue;
                case .Network : nOn(isActive, newValue); tabMap.1 = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
    //tuple used to represent a fixed set of tab isActive navigation states
    var tabMap = (false, false)
     
    func  nOn(_ old:Bool,_ new:Bool ){
        UINavigationBar.setAnimationsEnabled(new && !old)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible even with your custom tab view, because the issue is in rebuilding `ExploreTab()` when you switch tabs, so all content of that tab is rebuilt as well, so internal `NavigationView` on rebuilt is on first page.

Assuming you have only one `ExploreTab` in your app (as should be obvious), the possible solution is to make it `Equatable` explicitly and do not allow SwiftUI to replace it on refresh.

So

```
struct ExploreTab: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return true    // prevent replacing ever !!
    }

    var body: some View {
       // ... your code here
    }
}
```

and

```
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        switch displayedTab {
        case .explore: ExploreTab().equatable()      // << here !!
        case .network: NetworkTab()
        }
        CustomTabView(displayedTab: $displayedTab)   //This is the Custom TabBar
    }
```

**Update: tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14** - works as described above (actually the same idea works for standard containers)

Here is a quick demo replication of `CustomTabView` with test environment as described above.

[image: demo]

Full module code:

```
struct ExploreTab: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return true    // prevent replacing ever !!
    }

    var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Go", destination: Text("Explore"))
       }
    }
}

enum TestTabs {
    case explore
    case network
}

struct CustomTabView: View {
    @Binding var displayedTab: TestTabs
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Explore") { displayedTab = .explore }
            Divider()
            Button("Network") { displayedTab = .network }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 80).background(Color.yellow)
    }
}

struct TestCustomTabView: View {
    @State private var displayedTab = TestTabs.explore

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            switch displayedTab {
                case .explore: ExploreTab().equatable()      // << here !!
                case .network: Text("NetworkTab").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            CustomTabView(displayedTab: $displayedTab)   //This is the Custom TabBar
        }

        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm. This didn't work. When i clicked another tab, and then clicked back, the view seemed to be still be replaced, because it was back at root.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the files of this project on GitHub? I literally copied the code you provided but it is still popping to root. I have Xcode 12 Beta and i am testing on iPhoneSE 2nd generation. It still does not work for me :/ I am confused.

Comment: Here is a zip file of my XCode12 project. does this work for you? --> [Zip File](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/files/4885541/TestTabBar.zip)